# How to hide console window dynamically from a c# wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

i am running a c# wpf application as a console application so i have both ,a wpf and console window .

i want the console window to hide on a button click in wpf window and reappear on another click .i don't want the window to close and open again,i just want to show/hide the window on button click so that i can see the debug messages when i click on the button .

I asked the question about how to open/close the console window programatically , and here is the solution [How to open/close console window dynamically from a wpf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600355/how-to-open-close-console-window-dynamically-from-a-wpf-application/11600466#11600466) .
But opening and closing gives me a exception every-time when the console window is cloase and  a console.writeline function is called .

Comment: Do you mind posting your code?

Comment: The code is too large and the question is not related to any specific portion of the code .

Comment: Could you not wrap your calls to Console.WriteLine, etc. So that if you don't have a console window displayed the wrapper either does not pass the call along to the (now non-existent console) or it catches the exception and either swallows it, or queues all the writes for a time when the console is available again.

Comment: See this different solution to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: @ColinMackay i tried to do that , but there are so many console.writeline calls in the application .

Comment: @rajat live in Zuari Nagar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application) solution seems to work ,i ignored it as it was for console application and not for wpf applications.