# How to be dynamically either console application or Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small application who should be executed in **two modes**: non UI or WPF Window. It should depend on command line arguments.

In each mode, I need to show some feedback log:

1. In WPF Window mode, WPF is going to take care of visualizing logs,
2. In no UI mode, I need a console to show logs. If my app have been started from a console (mainly cmd.exe), I'd like to use it without opening a new one. If my app have been started outside of a console (double click on explorer, a CreateProcess, ...), I need to create a new console to output my results and wait for a Readkey to close it.

I have found:

- how I can create a new console:
  [How to open/close console window dynamically from a wpf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600355/how-to-open-close-console-window-dynamically-from-a-wpf-application),
- how to get current console windows handle to show/hide it:
  [Show/Hide the console window of a C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application)

And I know I can statically choose between "Windows Application" or "Console Application" in project property.

Choosing "Windows Application", GetConsoleWindow() is always 0 and I don't see how to reuse a previous console.

Choosing "Console Application", I can reuse a previous console but when started from explorer in WPF Window mode, a console is created under my WPF main window.

The question is: **how can an application be really dynamic?** Either in WPF Window mode, with only a WPF windows (and no console at all) or in non UI, with only one console (starting one or a new created one).

Comment: I think it's not related to WPF but only rooted in subsystem in PE header and main/winmain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a lot easier in Winforms, but its not too hard.

Start off with a WPF Application Project (not a console application project with WPF windows).

Create a new Program.cs class in the root directory, add the following code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void FreeConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool madeConsole = false;
        if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "console")
        {

            if (!AttachToConsole())
            {
                AllocConsole();
                Console.WriteLine("Had to create a console");
                madeConsole = true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Now I'm a console app!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (madeConsole)
                FreeConsole();
        }
        else
        {
            WpfApplication1.App.Main();
        }
    }


    public static bool AttachToConsole()
    {
        const uint ParentProcess = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        if (!AttachConsole(ParentProcess))
            return false;

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Attached to console!");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now you have a console app or a WPF app. In the Properties, set the start up object as the `Program.Main` method. In the example above, WpfApplication1.App.Main is the old start up object (defined in the App.xaml.cs file).

<strike>**Edit** this misses one of your requirements about using the existing console and I will edit it as soon as I figure out how to stay in the same console window.</strike>

**New Edit** Now works to use the existing console!

Comment: I've already experiment this solution. **You are in the case: "Choosing Console Application"**. We can reuse a previous console but when started from explorer, a console is created under WPF main window.

Comment: @MuiBienCarlota I suggest you try what I did, when starting from windows explorer, you get no console window. I tested many times before posting, no window appears. You may be confused about the project type, this is a WPF Application, not a console application, so don't choose a console application when creating your project.

Comment: I did it on your first code and I just give a try to your last code. Starting from a WPF project, added your Program class with new main and changed "Startup object" to your main function and Output type to "Console Application". And I have a console created when my program is started from explorer.

Comment: I never said change the output type! Leave it as "Windows Application"!

Comment: Yes, it works with the the AttachConsole with ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS. Thanks.

Comment: I assumed with mistake that a winmain was required with Output type to "Windows Application".