# Why would a Console Application pops when reloading the Designer in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having this weird behavior:

Yesterday I was working on a WPF application on Visual Studio 2015 and I wanted to write some values to a console prompt while debugging so I [included a console with my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600355/how-to-open-close-console-window-dynamically-from-a-wpf-application).

Today, when I started visual studio, even without *Starting* the program, a console window pops up. This is weird. When traced it, it turned to be coming from loading the designer of visual studio:

Anyone has any idea why is that happening and how to fix it?

[image]

When I *Disable Running Project Code* I get this form where my ImageConrol looks like is kind of disabled, but the console never pops again:

[image]

Comment: The WPF editor runs parts of your application to provide a live preview. It's usually useful, but it can be annoying in some situations, such as the one you're in.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Also as (in other applications) the ImageControl shows the current image, live, so it keeps a hold of the image physical file and I can't rename, edit, delete, move the file.. etc because _it is being used by another program_.

Comment: Have you installed any 3rd party controls?

Comment: @Rohit Well I have DevExpress stuff, and also ReSharper installed. I use these packages with several applications yet this behavior does not happen with the other applications

Comment: XDesProc.exe is a design rendering process which is spawned by Visual studio in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display your control, WPF designer actually runs your code (not all of it, but still). So designer might execute your `AllocConsole` call, which leads to behavior you observe. To avoid this, do:

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) {
    AllocConsole();
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Comment: It happens because designer executes your AllocConsole method (I actually was able to reproduce this). Designer does not execute all code, so maybe before you used this console in a part which did not get executed). Don't forget to rebuild project when you apply this fix (or comment AllocConsole out).

Comment: You can see on your screenshot that console you opened belongs to XDesProc.exe process. This is WPF designer process. When you closed console belonging to this process - it tears down whole process, so eventually terminates WPF designer (you can also see this on your screenshot). Why closing that console terminates process you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11960299/5311735.

Comment: Yup, makes complete sense now so thanks for the link :)