# Attach Console to (java) process from WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I currently start a bunch of java processes from my WPF app using `Process`, normally those would run in their own window. However when I want to send commands to the java app from my WPF app it requires me to run it with
`StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` which causes the process to run without a console.

I've tried to look for answers here on SO ([How to open/close console window dynamically from a wpf application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600355/how-to-open-close-console-window-dynamically-from-a-wpf-application)) and a few others but most seem to be for the app to be either ran in console mode or in UI mode. Nothing about attaching a console to a `System.Diagnostics.Process`

This version would open a Console

```cs
namespace MMSG.Instances
{
    public abstract class JavaServer : Process
    {
        protected JavaServer(string workingDir)
        {
            StartInfo.FileName = "java";
            StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDir;
            StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
            EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        protected JavaServer(string ram, string workingDir, string jarLocation) : this(workingDir)
        {
            StartInfo.Arguments = $"-Xms{ram} -Xmx{ram} -jar \"{jarLocation}\"";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: With window]

however when trying to send input to the `Process`using `javaServer.StandardInput.WriteLine("stop");`
I get this error: `System.InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.` And as stated before setting that to false removes the Console window altogether.

Expected result: allow sending of commands to the process while still having a Console window.
Actual result: Either no commands or no Console

Comment: try to set " StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; "